# Change path of RabbitMQ WebSocket MQTT endpoint?

Tags: websocket, rabbitmq, mqtt

I am running a RabbitMQ instance that provides MQTT over websockets via the `rabbitmq_web_mqtt` plugin.

For legacy reasons, I need to support a non-default WebSocket URL.

I saw in the documentation it is possible to change the port via the `{ port, 1234 }` config, but I could not find any way to change the WebSocket URL. It is currently set to the default path of `/ws`

Is it possible to change the WebSocket URL without modifying the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been made configurable back September 2018. See [already mentioned ticket](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-web-mqtt/issues/21).

Add line:

```
# echo 'web_mqtt.ws_path = /mqtt' >> /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
# service rabbitmq-server restart
```

Now being accessible by (compliant) MQTT Clients. For instance at:

```
ws://192.168.210.84:15675/mqtt
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** RabbitMQ now allows configuration of the WebSocket URL. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58998487/1064917).

After some research, I found out that [the path is not configurable](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-web-mqtt/issues/21)